# Get text from a reapeater object - flex

Tags: apache-flex, text, repeater, label

I have a label that is using a repeater to get information form a database. Now I'm trying to pass the information in that label to another label component, but I haven't had any luck.

if I do a trace on the label in the repeater eg.

```
trace (Gotid.text);
```

I get this error in debug mode

warning: unable to bind to property 'user_name' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
undefined

Any ideas on how I go about getting information form Gotid to display as text in another label?

- k I'll try to make this as straight forward as possible

  ```
      private function Getid():void {
      var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
      stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConn;
      stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM tbl_animal WHERE animal_ptag='"+ptagInput.text+"'"; 
      stmt.execute();
      var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
      acGetid = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
      animalid.text = Gotid.text;
      trace (Gotid.text);
  }
  ```

-

```
    <mx:Repeater id="getidrepeater" dataProvider="{acGetid}">
<mx:Label x="30" y="362" text="{getidrepeater.currentItem.animal_id}" id="Gotid"/>  
</mx:Repeater>
<mx:Label x="30" y="388" text="Label" id="animalid"/>
```

Comment: throw up an example of your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it relates to your `user_name` error, but the `Gotid` field in your main component will be an array of Labels, not a single Label field.

See [`Referencing Repeated Components`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_the_repeater/) in this Adobe Docs page, for example.

Given that you're possibly getting multiple animals to fill in `Gotid` with, I don't know how you know which to fill in the `animalid` label.  If you assume you're only going to get one, you could do:

```
animalid.text = Gotid[0].text;
trace (Gotid[0].text);
```

Comment: Thanks, That seem to do what I was looking for. Is there a better way to accomplish this instead of a repeater if I'm only looking for one result?

Comment: I would probably get the data out of the SQLResult (`result.data[0]`) and use that to fill in a single UI component; you're going to have to deference the array somewhere, but at least the data knows it's supposed to be a single result.